# Json.load rising "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" even with an "anti_empty" condition

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I already post about my problem and I thought it was solved, but after a few time the error rise again. I'm gonna explain my program from the beginning.
I got a Json file that contain values permanently update by another program, I want to get an overlay that display those values, that means I got to open and read my json file every second (or more) with the "after()" method. (Im using tkinter for my overlay).
When I run my tkinter window without the other program that update the values, everything work perfectly, I can update manually a value and it will be update on the overlay.
When I run both programs together after an amount of time, I get the empty  json error, sometimes after 5 minutes, sometimes after 45 minutes, It's random.
I tried the following issues :
Issue 1 :

```
def is_json(): 
    with open ('my_json') as my_file :
        myjson = my_file.read()
    try: 
        json_object = json.loads(myjson) 
    
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e: 
        return False 
    return True
if is_json():
     with open ('my_json') as my_file:
         data = json.load(my_file)
else : 
     time.sleep(0.1)
```

Issue 2:

```
 while True:
     if os.path.getsize("/my_json") > 0:
        with open ('my_json') as my_file :
            myjson = my_file.read()
     else:
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

I tryed another one, but I dont want to code it again, that was a function that allow one program to read/write on the json only in "even" seconds and the other one can only do it in "odd" second.
I try this to avoid interactions, cause I think that's my problem, but none of those solutions worked.

Comment: `if is_json()` shouldn't be inside the function. Remove a level of indentation there.

Comment: Change `except ValueError` to `except json.JSONDecodeError`

Answer (score 0):

You should return the parsed JSON in the same function that has the `try/except`. Otherwise, the file could change between calling `is_json()` and `json.load()`.

```
def json_load_retry(filename, sleeptime=0.1):
    while True:
        with open(filename) as f:
            try:
                return json.load(f)
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                time.sleep(sleeptime)

myjson = json_load_retry('my_json', sleeptime=0.2)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I think, my overlay doesn't crash as much as before, but there is still a chance I tryied to "interact" with my json on the 2 programs in the same time. So I still got no solution, except trying another way to read/write my values, maybe on a database.
But I'm only starting to use json file and it's really fit well on my programs

Comment: The best solution is to use mutual exclusion, so you only one of the programs can access the file at a time.

Comment: That means in theory, my first solution that allowed only pair and impair second should be fine. But in fact this one is not reliable. I will maybe try to create a 3th program that can discuss with the others, but It will turn my program even more difficult to work on.

Comment: I don't think my solution should ever crash with a JSONDecodeError. It will just stay in the loop until it's able to read the file successfully.

Comment: I will try it, and we will see

Comment: I tryed your solution but the error still occur, I discuss about it with a friend, I need to use a multithreading librairy that allow access or not, to my file.